VBA solution to hide aa row when a drop doen value of complete is selected
I am trying to use conditional formatting in Excel to create a formula (if statement) that will hide any row  in Column A whose drop down has a value of complete.
I tried several variations of
IF Range(A3).value="Complete" Then Range(A3).EntireRow.Hidden = TRUE
This does not work for me.
Please help and thank you for helping.
UPDATE: I had to code in ALT F11 space.
I found this code online and adapted it for my needs.
This code works:
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Call HideRowCellTextValue

End Sub

Sub HideRowCellTextValue()
    Dim StartRow As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim iCol As Long
    Dim i As Long

    StartRow = 2 ' First row of the dataset
    LastRow = 1000 ' Last row of the dataset
    iCol = 1 ' Column address that holds the text value (Column D)

    For i = StartRow To LastRow
        If Cells(i, iCol).Value <> "Complete" Then
            Cells(i, iCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
            Cells(i, iCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

I plan to take this further by adding a toggle button.
Thank you to all who helped.

IF Range("A3").value="Complete" Then Range("A3").EntireRow.Hidden = TRUE Quotation marks required.

conditional formatting can't hidden rows.

The best you could achieve with Conditional Formatting is to change the font colour to white and make it appear the data has vanished, although the row will still be visible. You'd need to use VBA to actual hide the row.

I just recorded a macro, hiding a row, and it looks as follows:
selectedSheet.getRange("4:4").setRowHidden(true);

You might use this instead of altering the .Hidden property.
